# c++ parse two bytes to int

Tags: c++, int, byte

I have two bytes read from a sensor over I2C, these are stored as `unsigned char`. I do know which is the most significant byte, and which is the least significant byte.

```
unsigned char yawMSB;
unsigned char yawLSB;
```

How would I go about converting these two bytes of data, into a single `int`?

I've had this implemented properly in C# using

```
BitConverter.ToInt16(new byte[] { yawLSB, yawMSB }, 0)
```

Comment: How would you do it if the target type was `int16_t` and not `float`?

Comment: First of all you need to read the documentation for the sensor. What do the values in the bytes actually *represent*?

Comment: The values represent eular angles. I've had this working in C# using: 
`BitConverter.ToInt16(new byte[] { yawLSB, yawMSB }, 0)`

Comment: So your problem isn't really with the floating-point conversion, it's more about how to convert two 8-bit integer values into a single 16-bit integer value?

Comment: Oh crap, you're completely right. My bad, I'll edit the question.

Comment: When the high bit of `yawMSB` is set, do you expect a negative result? In other words, are you converting to a signed 16-bit integer?

Comment: It's for rotation of a sensor, I do not expect there to be the possibility for negative numbers.

Comment: @NanoBob: Well, that is fine, nothing has ever gone wrong because nobody expected the possibility of a sensor or other input device providing bad data.

Comment: Haha, I can imagine what you're getting at. @EricPostpischil, but if I did want it to take the sign bit in account, how would I do that (Just for curiosity's sake)

Comment: @NanoBob: `int32_t x = (int32_t) yawMSB << 8 | yawLSB; if (32768 <= x) x -= 65536;`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In a 16-bit integer, the top 8 bits are the *most* significant byte, and the low 8 bits are the *least* significant byte.

To make the most significant byte occupy the top bits, you need to shift its value up (by 8 bits), which is done with the left-shift bitwise operator `<<`.

Then to get the least significant byte you just add the low 8 bits using bitwise or `|`.

Put together it will be something like `yawMSB << 8 | yawLSB`.

Comment: The OP may want a 16-bit signed integer result, which `yawMSB << 8 + yawLS` does not handle when the high bit of `yawMSB` is set.

Answer (score 3):

> I do know which is the most significant byte, and which is the least significant byte.

- MSB means *Most* Significant byte.
- LSB means *Least* Significant byte.

> How would I go about converting these two bytes of data, into a single float?

You can then build a float whose value is:

```
const float yaw = yawMSB << 8 + yawLSB;
```

Actually, the value `yawMSB << 8 + yawLSB` is probably on a scale defined by your implementation. If it is true, and if it is a linear scale from `0` to `MAX_YAW`, you should define your value as:

```
const float yaw = float(yawMSB << 8 + yawLSB) / MAX_YAW; // gives yaw in [0.f, 1.f].
```

Comment: seems like the question has been edited in between. There is no `float` in the question anymore

Comment: The OP may want a 16-bit signed integer result, which `yawMSB << 8 + yawLS` does not handle when the high bit of `yawMSB` is set.

Comment: @EricPostpischil The scope of the question changed after I answered. I keep it as is because I'm lazy + SPD's answer is good.

Comment: @YSC: Even before the question changed, `yawMSB << 8 + yawLSB` may have undefined behavior because it can overflow if `int` is 16 bits.

Comment: @EricPostpischil `yawMSB << 8 + yawLSB` is unsigned, no overflow possible.

Comment: @YSC: The integral promotions are performed on the left operand of `<<`. The integral promotions convert `unsigned char` to `int`. Then, if `int` is 16 bits, the shift by eight bits can overflow.